# ReactJs :- Failed to load js resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: html, reactjs, webserver

I am starting to learn react.js and was doing a simple Hello program.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hello_container" class=""></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" ></script>
    <script>
      class Hello extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
        }
        render() {
          return React.createElement(
            'div',
            null,
            `Hello ${this.props.name}!`
          );
        }
      }
      ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Hello, {name: 'React'}, null), document.querySelector('#hello_container'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But i was running into an issue for these two script tags ,

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" ></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" ></script>
```

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden)
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

I found something on google  as to run the html code on a web server(https://) rather than from file system (file:///)
So i ran a local web server as **python3 -m http.server 1234**
and it worked . I got output as Hello React!.

But i want to know why i was getting forbidden error when running the code  from file system ?

Is it related to same origin  allow access ?
What is different in running html code from file system and on a web server?

Comment: You just forgot to import or use the React and ReactDOM objects : `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` and `import React from 'react';` before your class declaration

Comment: But it worked from a web server . I got desired output